# If $\mathbb{N}$ is partitioned into finitely many subsets, must one of the subsets be a finite basis?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, problem-solving, combinatorial-number-theory

I recently came across an interesting problem [in this document](https://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/archivedocs/1999_2000/lectures/9900lecturespdf/cnt.pdf) from the Berkeley Math Circle (year 2000). Namely, Problem 4 in page 2 asks:

**Problem.** A set $S$ of positive integers is called a **finite basis** if there exists some $n$ such that every sufficiently large positive integer can be written as a sum of at most $n$ elements of $S$. If the set of positive integers is divided into finitely many subsets, must one of them necessarily be a finite basis?

I do not have good intuition as to whether the answer is "Yes" or "No". If the answer were "No", it would seem very hard to come up with a counterexample (because showing that a particular infinite subset is *not* a finite basis seems daunting). On the other hand, if the answer were "Yes", it would require a proof that would work no matter how $\mathbb{N}$ were partitioned into finitely many subsets. Either case seems murky, and it is unclear to me how to proceed. If I were to bet, I would think the answer is "Yes".

I would appreciate any insight on this problem. Thank you!

Comment: @jackson Why is that so? If I understand correctly, the set $\{2 + 2n \mid n \geq 0\}$ is a finite basis because for any number $m$ in the set with $m \geq 6$, I can write $m$ as the sum of two distinct numbers in the set: $m-2$ and $2$.

Comment: @jackson Oh, right, I misread the problem. You're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Suppose that for every integer $N$, there exists an integer $k > N$ with no elements in $A$ between $k$ and $k^2$, and we'll prove this shows $A$ isn't a finite basis. To see this, suppose $nA = \mathbb{N}$. Find a $k > n$ according to the assumption, and look at $k^2$. Since all summands in the representation must be $\leq k^2$, but there are no elements in $A$ between $k$ and $k^2$, all of them must be less than $k$, so the maximum value is $n k < k^2$.

Now we will partition $\mathbb{N}$ to two sets, each having this property. We will start with both sets empty, and alternatively create a gap in each:

$$A = \{2,3,4,5^2+1,..,(5^2+1)^2, ((5^2+1)^2+1)^2+1, ...\}$$
$$B = \{1,5,6,...,5^2,(5^2+1)^2+1,...,((5^2+1)^2+1)^2, ...\}$$

It's easy to see both sets have the desired property, so neither is a finite basis.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for this very clever construction!